# Counting number of occurrences in numpy 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1,2],[1,1], [2,1],[2,2],[3,2],[3,2], [3,1], [4,2],[4,1]])
print(a)
```

I need to count how many values of 1 or 2 occur in column 2 for each value in column 1.
For example when x=3 in column 1, there are two instances of the value 2 and one instance of the value 1 in column 2.

Any direction on how to complete this would be appreciated! I think I could do some sort of for loop with np.unique but I am not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your comment, if you want list of lists format, try this:

```
out = [[k, *np.unique(a[a[:,0] == k,1], return_counts=True)[1]] 
                                              for k in np.unique(a[:,0])]

Out[838]: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [4, 1, 1]]
```

For 2D-array

```
out = np.array([[k, *np.unique(a[a[:,0] == k,1], return_counts=True)[1]] 
                                                 for k in np.unique(a[:,0])])

Out[850]:
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [4, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

---

A simple way is using dict comprehension with `collections.Counter` and `np.unique`

```
from collections import Counter

out = {k: Counter(a[a[:,0] == k,1]) for k in np.unique(a[:,0])}

Out[821]:
{1: Counter({2: 1, 1: 1}),
 2: Counter({1: 1, 2: 1}),
 3: Counter({2: 2, 1: 1}),
 4: Counter({2: 1, 1: 1})}
```

Comment: I am going to apply this to a bigger set of data so do you know how to get this into an array format : x value, number of 1s, number of 2s?

Comment: could you add your desired output to your question to make it clearer on array format you mention?

Comment: yes, sorry!

[1 1 1]
[2 1 1]
[3 1 2]
[4 1 1]

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but in my "real" data set, the steps in the first column aren't incremental

Comment: @okvoyce: check my edited answer. This answer doesn't depend on the order of first column, so you don't have to worry about the incremental step in first columns

Comment: Thankyou for this! Rather than having a list of lists could it be a 2D array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your values in the first column go from 1 to *N* and in the second column from 1 to *M*, this is one very simple and fast way to do that:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2], [4, 1]])
c = np.zeros(a.max(0), np.int32)
np.add.at(c, tuple(a.T - 1), 1)
# c[i, j] contains the number of times
# the second column value is j + 1 when
# the first column value is i + 1

# Print result
for i in range(c.shape[0]):
    print(f'Count result for {i + 1}')
    for j in range(c.shape[1]):
        print(f'    Number of {j + 1}s: {c[i, j]}')
```

Output:

```
Count result for 1
    Number of 1s: 1
    Number of 2s: 1
Count result for 2
    Number of 1s: 1
    Number of 2s: 1
Count result for 3
    Number of 1s: 1
    Number of 2s: 2
Count result for 4
    Number of 1s: 1
    Number of 2s: 1
```

This works simply by making an array `c` of zeros and then basically adding one to every row/column of `c` indicated by each row of `a`. Conceptually, it is equivalent to `c[a[:, 0] - 1, a[:, 1] - 1] += 1`. However, doing that will probably not work, because `a` contains repeated rows, so NumPy ends up counting only one of those. To do that correctly, you need to use the [`at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method of the [`np.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) ufunc (this method is available in other ufuncs too, see [Universal functions (ufuncs)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html)). This adds the given value at each position (`tuple(a.T - 1)` makes a tuple with the row indices and the column indices) counting repeated positions correctly.

Comment: @okvoyce You should just need to concatenate the initial column like: `result = np.concatenate([np.arange(1, len(c) + 1)[:, np.newaxis], c], axis=1)`.

Comment: Thats great, thank you!

Could you please explain what each bit of the code is doing? I want to make sure I understand it :)

Comment: @okvoyce I added an explanation, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter np array with the condition then use `unique` method to get count

try below solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2], [4, 1]])

b = a[np.any(a == 3, axis=1)]

print(len(b[np.any(b == 2, axis=1)])) #output: 2
print(len(b[np.any(b == 1, axis=1)])) #output: 1

unique, counts = np.unique(b, return_counts=True)

print(dict(zip(unique, counts))) #output: {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

**Short solution:**

```
unique, counts = np.unique(a[np.any(a == 3, axis=1)], return_counts=True) #replace 3 with x

print(dict(zip(unique, counts)))
```

**output:**

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```